# Have to enter something twice in scanner when using thread - Java

Tags: java, multithreading

For some reason, I have to enter something twice for it to print out in Java when Using Scanner in a thread. I dont know why this is, but IT is very annoying. Because of this, My message sends through the socket and gets to the other person but does not show it to the person sending it, but on the second try it shows to the person who sent it but it doesnt get to the person that should receive it!
(If something  doesnt look like its from the Java API, its because its a Test Class for My API)
Note: The code is the exact same on both sides, except they use different ports.

```
private static UDPSocket TestUDP;
private static String Username = "9843";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        TestUDP = new UDPSocket(9844);
        TestUDP.defineDefaultAddress("localhost", 9843);
        Username = "Lawton";
        System.out.println("You set your name to: " + Username);
        new Thread(new Receive()).start();
        new Thread(new Send()).start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

static class Send implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        try {
            while (true) {
                Scanner UserInput = new Scanner(System.in);
                TestUDP.send("0x00", Username + ": " + UserInput.nextLine());
                System.out.println(Username + ": " + UserInput.nextLine());
                Thread.sleep(1);
            }
        } catch (Exception E) {
            System.err.println("There was a error.");
        }
    }
}

static class Receive implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        try {
            while (true) {
                byte[] Message = TestUDP.receive();
                System.out.println(Packet.decrypt(Message));
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a variable to avoid calling `scanner.nextLine()` twice:

```
Scanner UserInput = new Scanner(System.in);
String readUsername = UserInput.nextLine();
TestUDP.send("0x00", Username + ": " + readUsername);
System.out.println(Username + ": " + readUsername);
```